# How to subtract dates

Tags: python, django

Hey thanks for checking the question

First, see my code

```
class ConfirmationKey(models.Model):
key = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.EmailField()
confirmation_key = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
key_generated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
key_valid_till = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    if self.key is None or len(self.key)== 0 :
        self.key = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(20)).decode()
        self.confirmation_key = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(8)).decode()
        self.key_generated_at = datetime.datetime.now() 
        self.key_valid_till = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    
    super().save(*args,**kwargs)
  
def is_valid(self):
    """Returns weather the key is still valid or not"""
    if datetime.datetime(self.key_valid_till) < datetime.datetime.now():
        return True
    return False
```

Now , in the sceond function, how can I subtract self.key_valid_till from current time — where key_valid_till  is stringfied datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)

Answer (score 1):

`key_valid_till` does not need to be re-cast as a datetime. The ORM does this for you.

```
def is_valid(self):
    """Returns weather the key is still valid or not"""
    if self.key_valid_till =< datetime.datetime.now():
        return True
    return False
```

To test if the `key_valid_till`is 10 mins old, try this:

```
def is_valid(self):
    """Returns weather the key is still valid or not"""
    ten_mins_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    return self.key_valid_till =< ten_mins_ago
```